# SQL query not giving result as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, amazon-redshift, partition-by

I needed some help. I have the following table (sample showing below):

```
EmpID     | Type | timestamp           | block_id
----------------------------------------------------
    1     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 01:13:15 | AB12D
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 05:13:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 07:13:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 08:13:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 10:13:15
    1     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 13:13:00 | 1X1#1
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15
    1     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 13:15:15
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 14:13:00
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 15:13:00
    1     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 16:13:37
    2     |  'R' | 2018-04-15 04:15:00 | __08XA
    2     |  'P' | 2018-04-15 04:20:00
    2     |  'D' | 2018-04-15 05:11:33
```

And I'm trying to get an output as follows:

```
EmpID  | begin_timestamp     | end_timestamp      | block_id | P_count | D_count
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 2018-04-15 01:13:15 |2018-04-15 10:13:15 | AB12D    | 3       | 3
1      | 2018-04-15 13:13:00 | 2018-04-15 16:13:37| 1X1#1    | 3       | 3
2      | 2018-04-15 04:15:00 | 2018-04-15 05:11:33| __08XA   | 1       | 1
```

i.e., these are sort of blocks and each empId can have multiple blocks. So from the above sample table, empID '1' has 2 blocks (beginning from row 1 to row 7), and 2nd block from row 8 to row 14; empID 2 has 1 block, row 14 to row 16.

`block_id` is an alphanumeric field and can have any random values. Also the table is not ordered like shown above, it's just for explanation purposes. I am on redshift and have the following query so far:

```
select CAST(timestamp AS DATE) as date, execution_id, min(timestamp) as begin_timestamp, max(timestamp) as end_timestamp, new_block_id, 
sum(case when Type = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) as P_count,
              sum(case when Type = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as D_count
from (
    select *,
    max(block_id) over (partition by EmpID order by timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) new_block_id  from myTable
) d
group by EmpID, new_block_id, CAST(timestamp AS DATE)
order by EmpID, new_block_id, CAST(timestamp AS DATE)
```

But this is not working as it's not giving accurate results. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is `lag(ignore nulls)`, but Postgres does not support that.

Instead, you can use the timestamp of the non-NULL value and use that to define the groups.

```
select date_trunc('day', timestamp) as date, execution_id,
       min(timestamp) as begin_timestamp, max(timestamp) as end_timestamp,
       max(block_id) as block_id,
       sum(case when Type = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) as P_count,
       sum(case when Type = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as D_count
from (select t.*,
             max(case when block_id is not null then timestamp end) over 
                 (partition by EmpId
                  order by timestamp
                  rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                 ) as grp
      from myTable t
     ) t
group by empId, grp, date_trunc('day', timestamp)
```

Comment: What do you mean "you can use the timestamp of the non-NULL value and use that to define the groups"? What if there is another EmpID with the same timestamp etc.?

Comment: @Anjali . . . That doesn't make a difference.  `empId` is part of the partition by and group by clauses.

Comment: Is there a way to implement lag(ignore null) as a workaround here?